# How to make the console output window stay open in Visual Studio 2015 stay open when extra input is given?

Tags: c, windows, console, visual-studio-2015, windows-console

I wrote the following program in Visual Studio 2015-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PRAISE "You are an extraordinary being."
int main(void)
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
{
    char name[40];

    printf("What's your name? ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Hello, %s. %s\n", name, PRAISE);

    getchar();
    getchar();
    getchar();
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

The program runs fine in all cases. But the console window stays open when I provide "Shabbir", "Shabbir K", and "Shabbir Kh" as inputs. The console window won't stay open if I provide "Shabbir Kha" as input.

As you can see, the console window stays open until the second word reaches three character length. It doesn't stay open if the second word is three or more characters long.

The same program doesn't show any problems in Code Blocks 13.12.

Comment: Don't call `fflush(stdin)` - it's UB in the general case.

Comment: when calling scanf(), 1) put a size modifier on the %s,  I.E. `scanf("%39s", name);`  so the user cannot overflow the input buffer.  Use 39 for the 40 byte name[] array because scanf() appends a NUL char on string input.  2) always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: Thank you, @PaulR. I didn't know it was undefined behaviour. Our instructor taught us to use `fflush(stdin)` for preventing unwanted user input from messing our program. Could you suggest a more portable way to do the same job?

Comment: @ShabbirKhan: there is no simple, convenient and portable method - you can use user3629249's method below in some cases though. There are also quite a few good relevant questions and answers here on StackOverflow if you want to read up on this subject.

Comment: @PaulR: Alright, thanks! I will do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to keep the window open:

```
while( getchar() != EOF );
getchar();
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. It totally works. I was actually testing with these inputs because the book I am learning from used two words.

Comment: By the way, I have to close the window using the X button now. Is there any way to close the console window with a keyboard input in the you have given?

Comment: You can hit Control-Z (Windows) or Control-D (proper operating systems) to signal EOF rather than closing the window manually.